# Prove that the intersection of two ideals in a ring $R$ is also an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that the intersection of two ideals in a ring $R$ is also an ideal. R is a commutative ring.

I've seen many proofs about an ideal, but the proofs aren't identical. Sometimes one proves this way and another that way. So I want to make sure my proof is correct also.

The steps I took to prove is:

Let $I, J$ be ideals of $R$ and $K = I \cap J$

First, Show that $K$ is a subring of $R$

1. Show that if $p,q \in K,$ then $pq \in K$
2. Show that if $p,q \in K$ then $p - q \in K$
3. Show that $0 \in K$ to prove K is not empty.

Secondly, prove that $K$ is ideal. So I need to show that:

For all $r \in R$ and for all $i \in K, ri \in I$ (Since R is commutative, I don't need to show the other one, i.e. $ir$)

Answer (score 1):

An ideal need not be a subring. So you only need to prove 2. and 3. and the last assertion.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not overseeing something, then you don't need your first step, since if you show that $rk \in K$ for all $r \in R, k \in K$ you automatically get $1$. In general if you want to show that $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$, it suffices to show that $0 \in I, a+b \in I$ for $a,b \in I$ and $ra \in I$ for all $r \in R$.